# Countable connected space where removing $1$ point destroys connectedness

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there a countable connected space $(X,\tau)$ such that for all $x\in X$ the space $X\setminus\{x\}$ is not connected any more with the induced subspace topology?

Comment: Can’t resist: The one point space satisfies this.

Comment: @Thomas: But the empty space is connected!

Comment: @FredRohrer This is a convention, but usually, I would say no. For the same reason that 1 isn't prime. Otherwise you cannot say that a space uniquely decomposes into a disjoint union of connected spaces...

Comment: @FredRohrer: It depends on the convention indeed.

Comment: @Najib: Surely this is a convention (or, rather, depends on the definition of connectedness). I think it is more important to be able to say that every point lies in a unique maximal connected subspace (i.e., its connected component). This is possible if the empty space is connected (which is by the way in accordance with Bourbaki). But this has been discussed on MO before...

Comment: @Najib: The (topological) reason that 1 is not prime is that the empty space is not irreducible.

Comment: @FredRohrer Your statement is also true if $\varnothing$ is not connected. I think there are many reasons to want it to not be connected: unique decomposition in connected components; $\hom(X,-)$ preserves coproducts if $X$ is connected; for a (path-)connected space, $\pi_0(X) = *$; a product is connected iff both factors are connected. (This isn't off the top of my head, I'm reading [this](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/empty+space#connectedness).) Anyway, this is a bit tangential, and as you say we're certainly rehashing old arguments...

Comment: Actually one might argue that there are *three* different classes: empty (no pieces); connected (one piece); disconnected (more than one piece).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\mathbb{R}$ be with its usual topology, and let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{Z}$ defined by:
$$
f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
2k & x=2k,\text{ where } k\in\mathbb{Z}\\ 
2k+1 & 2k<x<2k+2,\text{ where } k\in\mathbb{Z}
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Let $X$ be $\mathbb{Z}$ with the quotient topology induced by $f$.

Comment: In other words it is the Alexandroff topology for the partial order$$\cdots<a_{-3}>a_{-2}<a_{-1}>a_0<a_1>a_2<a_3>\cdots,$$right?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Indeed

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე what endpoint?

Comment: I was responding to a comment that is no longer there. In any proper connected subspace of your example there are points $k$ such that either $k+1$ or $k-1$ does not belong to the subspace. It is natural (I think) to call these endpoints. If one removes such point from the subspace, what remains will be connected.

Answer (score 4):

The other answer describes the "Khalimsky line".  It is not $T_1$, but it is possible to obtain Hausdorff examples by starting with a countable connected Hausdorff space $X$, blowing up its points into more copies of $X$, and continuing this process infinitely many times. This ever-branching countable "tree" of $X$'s can be topologized so that it is connected, Hausdorff, and removing any point disconnects the space.

Comment: Could you provide more detail? I don't think it is easy to see. I certainly don't see it at all.

Answer (score -1):

To be a bit more explicit: in [Countable connected spaces](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1970-0263005-0) Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **26** (1970) 355-360 G. G. Miller describes a countable connected Urysohn space with a dispersion point.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question - it asks for a space where removal of _any_ point disconnects the space.

Comment: Indeed, I reacted more to the title than to the content of the question. Still, it indicates that a construction may be possible, though difficult.

Comment: The answer by @ForeverMozart seems to contain such construction, but I could not see the details, only the devil in them

Comment: The operative word being `seems'